# What causes the (big) size of python lists?

Tags: python, list, memory

I was messing around with [`sys.getsizeof`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys#sys.getsizeof) and was a bit surprised when I got to lists and arrays:

```
>>> from sys import getsizeof as sizeof
>>> list_ = range(10**6)
>>> sizeof(list_)
8000072
```

Compared to an array:

```
>>> from array import array
>>> array_ = array('i', range(10**6))
>>> sizeof(array_)
56
```

Turns out the size of a list of integers tends to 1/3 of the size of all its elements, so it can't be holding them:

```
>>> sizeof(10**8)
24
>>> for i in xrange(0,9):
...  round(sizeof(range(10**i)) / ((10**i) * 24.0), 4), "10**%s elements" % (i)
... 
(3.3333, '10**0 elements')
(0.6333, '10**1 elements')
(0.3633, '10**2 elements')
(0.3363, '10**3 elements')
(0.3336, '10**4 elements')
(0.3334, '10**5 elements')
(0.3333, '10**6 elements')
(0.3333, '10**7 elements')
(0.3333, '10**8 elements')
```

What causes this behavior, both of `list` being big but not as big as all its elements and `array` being so small?

Comment: First of all, `sys.getsizeof()` of a list does *not* measure how much memory the referenced objects take up. It's **just** the `list` object itself.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? For me, the memory size of the array is `4000056L`.

Comment: Python 2.7.3 [GCC 4.7.2] on linux2 (running on Debian, Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64)

Comment: Ah, I tested on Mac; on Linux another technique is used and the `.__sizeof__()` result doesn't accurately reflect the memory size. Perhaps a bug, I'll investigate.

Comment: [Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of **objects** it refers to.](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys#sys.getsizeof). So, a list contains only references to objects, not the actual objects.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: an `array` contains the values directly (it stores an array of bytes for efficiency). On Mac the memory consumption is correctly reflected. On linux *it is not*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what does `array.itemsize` returns on mac and linux?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I found the issue; my Mac uses 2.7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've encountered an issue with `array` objects not reflecting their size correctly.

Up until Python 2.7.3 the object's `.__sizeof__()` method did **not** reflect the size accurately. On Python 2.7.4 and newer, as well as any other new Python 3 release made after August 2012, a [bug fix was included](http://bugs.python.org/issue15424) that added the size.

On Python 2.7.5 I see:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(array_)
4000056L
```

which conforms with the 56 bytes of size my 64-bit system requires for the base object, plus 4 bytes per signed integer contained.

On Python 2.7.3, I see:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(array_)
56L
```

Python `list` objects on my system use 8 bytes per reference, so their size is naturally almost twice as big.

Comment: The object reference count and the heap linked list pointers, actually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Really? I'd think this has to do with the pointer size on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well yes, but the size of the list only reflects the size of the `PyObject` pointers afaik, so it doesn't really matter what those structures contain, does it?

Comment: @omz: indeed, I got something mixed up. Lists contain pointers, arrays contain an array of C `char` values. The size difference reflects the difference between those two C types, and that's enough. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The getsizeof function does not measure the size of the items in a container like a list. You need to add all the individual elements up.

[Here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) is a recipe to do this.

Reproduced here:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from sys import getsizeof, stderr
from itertools import chain
from collections import deque
try:
    from reprlib import repr
except ImportError:
    pass

def total_size(o, handlers={}, verbose=False):
    """ Returns the approximate memory footprint an object and all of its contents.

    Automatically finds the contents of the following builtin containers and
    their subclasses:  tuple, list, deque, dict, set and frozenset.
    To search other containers, add handlers to iterate over their contents:

        handlers = {SomeContainerClass: iter,
                    OtherContainerClass: OtherContainerClass.get_elements}

    """
    dict_handler = lambda d: chain.from_iterable(d.items())
    all_handlers = {tuple: iter,
                    list: iter,
                    deque: iter,
                    dict: dict_handler,
                    set: iter,
                    frozenset: iter,
                   }
    all_handlers.update(handlers)     # user handlers take precedence
    seen = set()                      # track which object id's have already been seen
    default_size = getsizeof(0)       # estimate sizeof object without __sizeof__

    def sizeof(o):
        if id(o) in seen:       # do not double count the same object
            return 0
        seen.add(id(o))
        s = getsizeof(o, default_size)

        if verbose:
            print(s, type(o), repr(o), file=stderr)

        for typ, handler in all_handlers.items():
            if isinstance(o, typ):
                s += sum(map(sizeof, handler(o)))
                break
        return s

    return sizeof(o)
```

If you use that recipe and run this on a list, you can see the difference:

```
>>> alist=[[2**99]*10, 'a string', {'one':1}]
>>> print('getsizeof: {}, total_size: {}'.format(getsizeof(alist), total_size(alist)))
getsizeof: 96, total_size: 721
```

Comment: But that does not explain the situation in the case of an `array`.

Comment: An `array` is **not** a container. On Mac I get an accurate reflection of the size, on Linux you do not.